# adding more then one layouts to navigation drawer in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

i have a drawer layout and two fragments. i want to add that fragments on navigation drawer. there are two container layouts for fragments: @+id/container1 is for fragment1 and @+id/container2 is for fragment2. but i can add only one, another fragment isn't shown. when i set container1 for fragment1 and container2 for fragment2, only fragment1 is shown. then i set container1 for fragment2 and container2 for fragment1. but that time only fragment2 is shown. how can i add that two layout on navigation drawer?

here is my main layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<!-- my main content -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/color_accent_pink">

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/newsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- my navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@color/myDrawerBackground">

    <!-- container layout for fragment1 -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/merhabaText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Hello!"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- container layout for fragment2 -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/merhabaText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Hi!"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It might be an error that's only in your question and not your project, but I noticed your second container has the line `android:layout_below="@+id/container"`, which looks like it should actually be `android:layout_below="@id/container1"`

Comment: i used @id/container1 but it didn't solve the problem. nothing changed.